# Open matlab file with no extension in python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to open a file with no extension in python.

After some search on the internet, this file looks like a Matlab file.

But I can't make sure that this is a Matlab file or not, because I have no background about Matlab. (It looks like cell or struct)

Below are some contents of that file.

```
{
chuck=[
{
chuck_id=CHUCK_ID_1,
coarse_zero={
scan_data={
raw_result={
scan_pair=[
{
scan=[
{
ht=[
{
nr_samples=0,
sample=[
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
...
0.0
],
has_invalid_data=FALSE
},
{
nr_samples=0,
sample=[
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
...
0.0
],
has_invalid_data=FALSE
}
],
z_capture=0.0
},
{
nr_samples=0,
sample=[
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
...
```

I tried loadmat of scipy and loadtxt of numpy, but it doesn't work.

- in case of loadmat

> line 225, in loadmat
> MR, _ = mat_reader_factory(f, **kwargs)
>
> line 74, in mat_reader_factory
> mjv, mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)
>
> line 231, in get_matfile_version
> raise ValueError('Unknown mat file type, version %s, %s' % ret)
>
> ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 10, 48

- in case of loadtxt

> line 1146, in loadtxt
> for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
>
> line 997, in read_data
> items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>
> line 997, in 
> items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
>
> line 734, in floatconv
> return float(x)
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '{'

Do you have any idea what type of that file is and how open it in python?

If you need more contents of file, I can provide it but this file have almost 12 MB and it have confidential problem.

Comment: The kind of file that `loadmat` handles doesn't have any human readable text.  `loadtxt` expects neat rows and columns of text.

Comment: But **loadtxt** doesn't work also as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, because the file doesn't have the neat CSV style of layout.  What exactly is that 'contents' display?  The actual text of the file, or something else.   I see lots of variable names, but only a small bit of data.  It looks incomplete.

Comment: Actually, the rest of file have the same patterns. I added some more. The file have no extension, but it can be opened via texteditor.

And that is exactly what I wanna know: What file has that style. In my thinks, that looks like Matlab file: cell or struct, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Looks like it could be read with ordinary python file `readlines`, but making sense of and creating useful data structures will require iteration on the lines and string parsing.  It's not a standard format (that I'm know of).  It looks vaguely `xml` like, except it has `=` instead of `:` (dictionary notation) and no quotes.

Comment: Where @hpaulj said "xml" he meant "json". It does look a lot like json, maybe if you replace all `=` with `:` you can read it in Python with a json parser. This has nothing to do with MATLAB, it's not valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, you are right, I was thinking `json`.  `xml` is quite different, and not something I see very often in `numpy` related questions.

Comment: Thanks, CrisLuengo and hpaulj. I will try replacing all = with : and parsing it into json.